# How to call $http.post from other controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this controller below. Upon page load the $http service that you see below is executed.

Now, how can I call and execute the controller's $http.post(...) part AGAIN from other controller.

---

```
 controller: function ($scope, $element, $http) {

    function par() {               
        var xxx= null;
        xxx = $scope.$parent.$root.ParentItems['xxx'].xxx;
        var det = { xxx: xxx};              
        return det;
    }


 $http.post('/api/values/entries/GoHere', par()).success(function (salData) {

      var buildSHGraph = function (shData) {
        //code code codes...
      }

      $scope.Array1 = [];

      angular.forEach(salData, function (evt) {
         //Code Code Codes
      });

     buildSHGraph($scope.Array1);

 });

 }
```

Comment: you can use factory or service for that. when u put that in to a service or factory its a reusable part, so u can call that service from any of your controller

Comment: move $http method into service and pass service in any controller and call it.

Answer (score 5):

You can create shared service

```
angular.module("yourAppName", []).
    factory("mySharedService", ['$http', function($http){
        return {
           callPost: function(params) {
               return $http.post('/api/values/entries/GoHere', params)
                    .success()
                    .error();
           }
        };
}]);
```

Then inject it into any controller and call necessary service method.

```
function FirstController($scope, mySharedService) {
    $scope.params = {//..//};
    $scope.result1 = mySharedService.callPost(params)
                    .success(function(result){//..//});  
}

function SecondController($scope, mySharedService) {
    $scope.params = {//..//};
    $scope.result2 = mySharedService.callPost(params)
                    .success(function(result){//..//});  
}
```

Comment: thanks. This works however I can only move this part "$http.post('/api/values/entries/GoHere', par);" into the factory. the success part is still on my controller. Ive tried to put it in a method like this. "mySharedService.callPost(par()).success(method());" still in the controller but i can't access the method. Do you know how to?

Comment: Hi @Artyom what if I need the same implementation of FirstController and SecondController? I have a long code inside the enclosed .success(function(result){//.. Long code ..//}) that is why I don't want it to repeat in another controller...

Comment: @user1960948, you can use the shared service too for that task. You need to move the logic in the service and inject this service to necessary controller.